# Which metric spaces embed isometrically in $\ell_p$?

Tags: gn.general-topology, banach-spaces, metric-spaces, geodesics, embeddings

It is known that each metric space $X$ embeds isometrically in the Banach space
$\ell_\infty(X)$ of bounded (not necessarily continuous) functions $X \to \mathbb R$. Since $\ell_\infty(X)$ does not care about the topology on $X$ it can be viewed as a "sequence space" of all functions $\alpha \to \mathbb R$ for the cardinal number $\alpha= |X|$.

I am curious about which metric spaces we can embed in $\ell_p(\alpha)$ for some cardinal $\alpha$. Here we define

$$\ell_p(\alpha) = \Big \{x: \alpha \to \mathbb R: \sum_{a \in \alpha} |x(a)|^p  \text{ converges}\Big\}$$

Convergence is understood as the net of elements $x(A) =  \sum_{a \in A} |x(a)|^p  $ indexed by the finite subsets  $A \subset \alpha$ under reverse-inclusion.

The big difference between the $\ell_p$ and $\ell_\infty$ spaces is the former are **absolutely convex** and the latter are not. One definition of absolute convexity is that for any two points there is a unique geodesic connecting them. Namely the shortest line segment joining the two points. One the other hand for $\ell_\infty(2)$ say there are many geodesics connecting $(0,-1)$ to $(0,1)$. For example we have also the line segment from $(0,-1)$ to $(b,0)$ to $(0,1)$ for all $|b| \le 1$.

Clearly this unique geodesic condition is necessary for a metric space to embed in some $\ell_p(\alpha)$. I wonder is is is also sufficient? I cannot find any results about general embedding conditions online. I can only find results about embedding in Hilbert spaces, embeddings of finite metric spaces, and "approximate" embeddings in $\ell_p$.

Comment: You cannot have looked much if you ask whether every strictly convex Banach space (the usual term is not absolutely convex) embeds isometrically into $\ell_p$ for some  $ 1<p<\infty$.

Comment: You can start by looking at Deza, Laurent, Geometry of Cuts and Metrics, Springer, 1997, and Koldobsky-Konig, Aspects of the isometric theory of Banach spaces, in: Handbook of the geometry of Banach spaces, Volume 1.